# Testing rules for lots of combinations

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, rules, rule-engine

I need an advice on a system design for a game. 
There are heroes and there are bonuses. Bonuses can be applied to the heroes. There are also rules like: `If bonus B applied to hero H, then ...`. There are no rules for each and every combination hero-bonus, let's assume there is 50% of such combinations covered. If no rule specified, nothing happens.

Assuming there are 100 bonuses and 100 heroes, what is the best approach to design such system? I believe having each relation test gives much flexibility, but it is not the best from code readability and maintenance perspective. Also, if I am going to add either hero, or bonus, it will become a huge piece of refactoring.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"what is the best approach to design such system?"* That's rather broad. What specific problems does your design need to solve? For example, do you need to be able to efficiently look up what bonus (if any) applies to a particular combination, or combine the effects of all bonuses that currently apply to a given hero, or search for all heros who might get some effect from a particular bonus, or something else?

Comment: And what if the hero has a bonus already?  What happens with the second one? Furthermore if the interaction between bonus and hero is arbitrary, how do you expect users to learn it?  I would recommend that heroes have attributes, and bonuses interact with other bonuses and affect attributes.  Then you can have far fewer bonuses, and adding heroes and/or bonuses becomes easier.  (Play *Empires and Puzzles* for an example of a game that fits this strategy.)